# Ribbon does not always appear for VSTO add-in, Word

Tags: ms-word, vsto, office-addins

I'm newbie with VSTO and having trouble getting my project started. I have an add-in for Word 2016 in VS 2017. When I open a docx file directly from windows file explorer, the ribbon tab appears and the button functions as it's supposed to. But if I open Word, then open a document, or create a fresh one in Word, or open Word by clicking 'start' in Visual Studio, my tab does not appear on the ribbon. I have tried adding my dll in manage COM Add-ins and it says "is not a valid Office Add-in", even though it otherwise works. The LoadBehavior in the registry is set to '3', meaning it should load automatically. This value stays regardless of whether the tab appeared or not. Any help would be hugemongously appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you get an error at runtime and Office hides your customizations automatically.

By default, if a VSTO Add-in attempts to manipulate the Microsoft Office user interface (UI) and fails, no error message is displayed. However, you can configure Microsoft Office applications to display messages for errors that relate to the UI. You can use these messages to help determine why a custom ribbon does not appear, or why a ribbon appears but no controls appear.

To show VSTO Add-in user interface errors

1. Start the application.
2. Click the File tab.
3. Click Options.
4. In the categories pane, click `Advanced`.
5. In the details pane, select `Show VSTO Add-in user interface errors`, and then click OK.

For Outlook, the `Show VSTO Add-in user interface errors` checkbox is located in the `Developer` section of the details pane. For other applications, the checkbox is located in the `General` section of the details pane.

Comment: I just made that change and will test it tomorrow. It's bedtime on my side of the pond and my eyes are getting blurry. Спасибо за совет. Thanks heaps.

Comment: I've just tried again and I don't get any messages. Frustrating.

Comment: An update on my question. I've found the problem but not the solution. I discovered I have two versions of office on my computer. The version that doesn't work is the one that the VSTO template in VS uses. How would I point VS to the version that works? Is the setting in the registry or somewhere in VS?

Comment: I have tried same process, I am not able to find the error logs in the ms word.
Can you tell me where can I find those error logs?

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved it: project properties > debug tab:
turned on "start external program" and entered the exe of the version I wanted. I found that out through the task manager, right-clicking program and clicking "open file location".